# SQL Server : alter table A while table B performing CRUD?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Should I break my database up into two under this scenario?

**Scenario**

While customers are creating, editing, saving orders in the `Order` table, the website owner calls a stored procedure to alter table properties in the `Email` table.

**Update**

The only relation the Order table has with the Email table is the userId (FK on Email table) . So, what are the ramifications if WHILE customer is placing an order, I am simultaneous adding say a nullable "CcAddressId" column to the Email table. Would problems occur with this order being successful?

**Questions:**

- Will either have a potential error if these events occurring simultaneously?
- Would it be better to break up the database into groups?

Comment: How are these tables related, if at all?  Is it possible for keys in either table to be edited?  More information about these topics and the structure of these tables might help you get a better answer.

Comment: This is what databases are made for.  No two events that modify the same data will ever actually occur exactly simultaneously; the database ensures they always happen in some order so the underlying data always remains consistent.  This is accomplished automatically by transactions and record/table locking.

Comment: Entity Framework (i.e. single DbContext/ObjectContext) cannot work with two databases at the same time. In addition to what @mellamokb said you may want to use optimistic concurrency to make sure that you are not overriding. Check this blog (it's a bit dated but still should be good as starting point) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/05/20/tip-19-how-to-use-optimistic-concurrency-in-the-entity-framework.aspx and search for "entity framework concurrency" using bing or google to find more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is not to break the database in two because you will lose the referential integrity enforced by your foreign keys, not to mention other issues that others brought up above.
What you need to do is find out if SQL Server will issue any kind of lock for your EMails table as you are inserting data into Orders table.
You can experiment and find out for yourself using this as a starting point:

http://aboutsqlserver.com/2012/04/05/locking-in-microsoft-sql-server-part-13-schema-locks/

Altering a table will try to issue a schema modification lock (SCH-M) which is incompatible with any other kinds of locks. Therefore, if there is any activity going on over the table being altered (which I assume there will be because foreign key constraints are being validated), your schema modification statement will be blocked for a long time.

This is why it is better to run schema altering statements when your database is NOT under heavy load.